# Store image path in a DB

Tags: laravel

I’m working on a CRUD system for inventory management, in which images for each product should be included. Every time that I try to save the path of the image in the DB this error appears:

> Undefined variable: image

My controller looks like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if (Auth::user('logistics')) {
        $product = $this->validate(request(), [
            'Product_Name' => 'required',
            'Amount'       => 'required|numeric',
            'MinAmount'    => 'required|numeric',
            'Status'       => 'required',
            'Supplier'     => 'required',
            'WebLink'      => 'required',
        ]);
        if ($request->hasFile('Product_Image')) {
            $image = Storage::putFile('public/pictures/LogInv/', $request->Product_Image);
        }
        $product['Product_Image'] = $image;
        $product['Employee_id'] = Auth::user()->id;
        LogisticsInv::create($product);

        return back()->with('success', 'Product has been added');
    } else {
        return view('/restricted_area');
    }
}
```

and my input looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="{{url('loginv')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12"></div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="Product_Image">Product Image:</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="Product_Image">
        </div>
    </div>
```

and `dd($request->all());` delivers this

> array:8 [▼   "_token" => "P7m8GP4A35G1ETUosduBSWtMpJuPaNILn2WI6Al3"
>   "Product_Image" => "6.jpg"   "Product_Name" => "asd"   "Amount" =>
>   "123"   "MinAmount" => "1"   "Status" => "Ok"   "Supplier" => "asd"
>   "WebLink" => "asd" ]

Comment: If your code don't enter in the `if ($request->hasFile('Product_Image'))` conditional `$image` won't be initialized. That's why you are getting that error.

Comment: @namelivia I tried that at the beginning, but when I put my code in the conditional, then Image is saved in the DB as NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if (Auth::user('logistics')) {
        $product = $this->validate(request(), [
            'Product_Name' => 'required',
            'Amount' => 'required|numeric',
            'MinAmount' => 'required|numeric',
            'Status' => 'required',
            'Supplier' => 'required',
            'WebLink' => 'required'
        ]);
        if ($request->hasFile('Product_Image')) {
            $image = Storage::putFile('public/pictures/LogInv/', $request->Product_Image);
            $product['Product_Image'] = $image;
        }
        $product['Employee_id'] = Auth::user()->id;
        LogisticsInv::create($product);
        return back()->with('success', 'Product has been added');
    } else {
        return view('/restricted_area');
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is gone, but now the image path appears as NULL in the DB

Comment: check `$request->hasFile('Product_Image'))` also `show dd($request->all())`;

Comment: dd($request->hasFile('Product_Image')); returns false

Comment: What `dd($request->all())`; after upload file

Comment: Just edited the post, dd($request->all()) is under how my input looks like

Comment: If you see `"Product_Image" => "6.jpg"`. That mean file actually not uploaded.

Comment: hmm, you are completely right. Then I have no Idea why is not being uploaded

Comment: try dd($_POST); global variable

Comment: returns the same as dd($request->all())

Comment: Okay, I will check it. file_uploads=On

Comment: And what is a problem??

Comment: couldn't find it, so I decided to start from scratch on the front end

Comment: so I found the error. I completely forgot that I was working on a modal, I just had to add enctype="multipart/form-data" to my modal form